# Woocommerce custom product calculator, how to update product price?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to make an website for the company i am hired to, we sell photo albums that are customisable a lot, so we can't just sell like simple product.
 I am using WordPress with WooCommerce
The woocommerce attributes variables doesn't give me enough options, i need an calculator not variations.
    So i created one, it looks like this:

```
    <div id="calculator_br">
    <form action="">
        <!-- <div id="covertype">
            <h4>Tip coperta:</h4>
            <div id="selector">
                <input type="radio" name="hm"> Handmade
                <span class="hidden hm">
                    <p id="hm2020">50</p>
                    <p id="hm2525">85</p>
                    <p id="hm3030">105</p>
                    <p id="hm2030">85</p>
                    <p id="hm2535">105</p>
                    <p id="hm3040">105</p>
                    <p id="hm2519">85</p>
                    <p id="hm3022.5">95</p>
                </span>
                <input type="radio" name="pe"> Piele Ecologica
                <span class="hidden pe">
                    <p id="hm2020">45</p>
                    <p id="hm2525">70</p>
                    <p id="hm3030">90</p>
                    <p id="hm2030">70</p>
                    <p id="hm2535">90</p>
                    <p id="hm3040">100</p>
                    <p id="hm2519">70</p>
                    <p id="hm3022.5">80</p>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div> -->
        <div id="dims">
            <p>Dimensiune:</p>
            <span class="size-form">
                <p>Patrat:</p>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="6.5" copertaprc="50" faceoffprc="0" old="25" checked="checked">20x20cm </br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="9" copertaprc="85" faceoffprc="0" old="30">25x25cm </br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="10" copertaprc="105" faceoffprc="0" old="35">30x30cm </br>
            </span>
            <span class="size-form">
                <p>Landscape:</p>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="9" copertaprc="85" faceoffprc="0" old="30">20x30cm </br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="10" copertaprc="105" faceoffprc="0" old="35">25x35cm </br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="12.5" copertaprc="115" faceoffprc="0" old="40">30x40cm </br>
            </span>
            <span class="size-form">
                <p>Portret:</p>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="8" copertaprc="85" faceoffprc="0" old="25">25x19cm </br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" filaprc="9" copertaprc="95" faceoffprc="0" old="30">30x22.5cm </br>
            </span>

        </div>

        <div id="col">
            <p>Numar Colaje:</p> 
            <input type="range" name="colaje" min="5" max="25" filaprc="15"><p id="range">15</p>
        </div>

        <div id="fof_wrp">
            <p>Face-Off:</p> 
            <input type="radio" name="foff" class="carton" filaprc="0" checked="checked">Carton (Gratuit) </br>
            <input type="radio" name="foff" class="catifea" filaprc="">Catifea </br>
            <span class="pret_fof">Pret: <p id="fof" style="display: inline;">0</p>lei</span></br>
        </div>

    </form>
    <span class="display-none">Pret pe fila: <p id="ppf" style="display: inline;"></p>lei</span></br>
    <span class="display-none">Pret coperta: <p id="cop" style="display: inline;"></p>lei</span></br>
    <!-- <span>Pret faceoff: <p id="fof" style="display: inline;"></p>lei</span></br> -->
    <span class="display-none">Pret grafica: <p id="grf" style="display: inline;"></p>lei</span>        
    </br>
    <p id="result" style="display: inline;">220lei</p>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


        $cart = $('input.carton');
        $catf = $('input.catifea');

        $cart.click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('focheck');
            $(this).removeClass('founcheck');
            $catf.removeClass('focheck');
            $catf.addClass('founcheck');
        });
        $catf.click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('focheck');
            $(this).removeClass('founcheck');
            $cart.removeClass('focheck');
            $cart.addClass('founcheck');
        });


        $('#dims input').click(function(){

            if ($(this).attr("checked", "checked")) {
                $val_ppf = $(this).attr('filaprc');
                $val_cop = $(this).attr('copertaprc');
                $val_cart = 0;
                $val_catf = $(this).attr('old');

                $('#fof_wrp .catifea').attr('filaprc', $val_catf);

                $('#ppf').text($val_ppf);
                $('#cop').text($val_cop);

                $('input[name="foff"]').click(function(){
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    if ($('#fof_wrp > input').prop('checked', true)) {
                        $fof_fin = $(this).attr('filaprc');
                        $('#fof').text($fof_fin);
                    }

                });
            }
        });

        $('div#col').mousemove(function(){

            $col = $(this).children('input').val();

            $('#range').text($col);

            if ($col > 20) {
                $('#grf').text('100');
            } else {
                $('#grf').text('80')
            }

        });

        $('form').click(function(){

            if ($('#fof').text().length > 0) {

                $ppfnr = parseInt($('#ppf').text(), 10);
                $copnr = parseInt($('#cop').text(), 10);
                $fofnr = parseInt($('#fof').text(), 10);
                $colnr = parseInt($('#range').text(), 10);
                $grfnr = parseInt($('#grf').text(), 10);

                $total = $colnr*$ppfnr + $copnr + $fofnr + $grfnr;

                $('#result').text('Total: ' + $total + 'lei');
                $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html($colnr*$ppfnr + $copnr + $fofnr + $grfnr + '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">lei</span>');
                $('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr('content',$colnr*$ppfnr + $copnr + $fofnr + $grfnr);
            } else {

                $('#result').text('Completati toate campurile!');

            }

        });

    });
```

Pretty beginner code but i did it, the calculator works like it should but when i add to cart the product goes with regular price, not the calculated price.
    This is my problem, how can i set the calcuated price as product price?

*I am sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

I got this code wich work but I dont know how to output the result of calculator to function.php where the code is inserted, to replace $price...

```
    function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
        global $post, $blog_id;
        $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price');
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $price = ($price[0]*2.5);
        return $price;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```